# boto3 cache session token not working

Tags: aws-sdk, boto3, aws-cli

Either there's something borked in my environment or this functionality is broken.  It appears it worked at one point according to the [blog](http://kinoshita.eti.br/2016/10/04/using-the-aws-api-with-python/) I followed:

What I'd like to do is run my script, enter the MFA. Then be able to run it again without entering MFA making use of cached session token.

The samples I've seen are:

```
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='w2-cf3')
ec2_client = session.client('ec2',region_name='us-west-2')
```

I'm then prompted for my mfa:

```
Enter MFA code:
```

I enter it and my code runs.  At this point, my session token should be cached, that's how it works in awscli. However, on the second run, instead of reading in my cached session for this profile, boto3 disregards and prompts me again for my MFA:

```
Enter MFA code:
```

Here's what my ~/.aws/config file looks like:

```
[profile default]
region = us-west-2
output = json

[profile w2-cf3]
region = us-west-2
source_profile = default
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::<accountid>:role/<role>
mfa_serial = arn:aws:iam::<accountid>:mfa/<user>
```

Here's what my ~/.aws/credentials file looks like:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=<access key>
aws_secret_access_key=<secret key>
```

Expected:  I expected the second time I run my script is would make use of the cached session token like it does in awscli.  The session token provided by AWS lasts 1 hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is discussed in the GitHub repo for botocore [here](https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/1148) and a [pull request](https://github.com/boto/botocore/pull/1157) has been submitted too and being discussed.

You're correct, this seems it was working back in 2014 but has been somehow removed, from the discussion on the thread mentioned above, this should be re-implemented soon, follow the pull request thread and make sure to upgrade when it is being release.

Comment: Look like the PR is closed and a new PR (https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/24582) was created to address the issue.