# Sagemaker session not caching MFA token

Tags: boto3, aws-sdk, amazon-sagemaker

Background: I'm assuming a cross-account role, then trying to use that to ingest data into feature groups, using the Sagemaker SDK. The cross-account role requires use of multi-factor authentication. However, it appears that this is not being cached, because I keep being prompted multiple times, to enter an MFA code.

Problem: How can I ensure that the MFA token is cached and don't have to keep re-entering it?

My `~/.aws/credentials` file with my own account login looks like this

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = ...
aws_secret_access_key = ...
region = us-east-1
```

and my `~/.aws/config` file with the other roles, looks like this

```
[profile data]
role_arn = <data ARN>
source_profile = default
region = us-east-1
mfa_serial = <Personal MFA serial>
duration_seconds = 14400

[profile sandbox]
role_arn = <sandbox ARN>
source_profile = default
region = us-east-1
mfa_serial = <Personal MFA serial>
duration_seconds = 3600
```

I'm creating a boto session, then assuming the `sandbox` role and using the new credentials to create a sagemaker client.

```
my_session = boto3.session.Session()
sts_client=my_session.client('sts')

credentials = my_session.get_credentials()

otp = input('Enter OTP: ')
assumed_role_object = sts_client.assume_role(
    RoleArn=<sandbox ARN>,
    RoleSessionName='newsession',
    SerialNumber=<Personal MFA serial>,
    TokenCode=otp
)
credentials=assumed_role_object['Credentials']

boto_session = boto3.session.Session( 
    aws_access_key_id=credentials["AccessKeyId"],
    aws_secret_access_key=credentials["SecretAccessKey"],
    aws_session_token=credentials["SessionToken"],
)

# to be really really explicit, I'm using the assumed role credentials again to create the Sagemaker client
sagemaker_client = boto_session.client('sagemaker',
    aws_access_key_id=credentials["AccessKeyId"],
    aws_secret_access_key=credentials["SecretAccessKey"],
    aws_session_token=credentials["SessionToken"]
)
sagemaker_session = Session(sagemaker_client=sagemaker_client, boto_session=boto_session)
```

Here, the feature group is created using the assumed role credentials, yet I have to specify `profile_name` AGAIN, otherwise it throws an access denied error.

```
feature_group = FeatureGroup(
        name=feature_group_name, sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session
    )
feature_group.ingest(df, profile_name='sandbox')
```

A couple of [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45023529/boto3-cache-session-token-not-working) [issues](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/1682) I've seen turned out to be bugs, but none have so far been reported for Sagemaker, so I'm not sure.

Comment: What is the maximum session duration for the role you're assuming?

Comment: @CoinGraham since I'm not specifying anything, it should be the default of 1 hour.